# Implementation for read_term_from_atom/3 in prolog

Tags: prolog, built-in

I want to know what the implementation code would look like for this built in predicate [read_term_from_atom/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read_term_from_atom/3) so that I can recreate the predicate myself.

Comment: The source code fo SWI Prolog is available online. If you don't know where to find it, try Googling "SWI Prolog source code".

Comment: I've downloaded the source code from https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel and can't find an implementation for this method in there, lots of explanations of what it does but nothing on how to write it yourself.

Comment: Actually it looks like they implement it using PERL, I'm wondering how to take an atom surrounded by quotes and put the value inside the quotes to a variable without using this built in. I'll post the my question on another question.

Comment: PERL?? No, it's in C. `src/pl-read.c`. You're probably seeing a bunch of `.pl` files, which is Prolog file extension.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redefine SWI-Prolog's **standard term input** you should redefine `read_term/3`via `redefine_system_predicate/1`

This directive may be used both in module **user** and in normal modules to redefine any system predicate.

If the system definition is redefined in module **user**, the new definition is the default definition for all sub-modules.

Otherwise the redefinition is local to the module. The system definition remains in the module system.

http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=redefine_system_predicate/1